# Align at multiple points in math environment

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

Consider the following equation:

[image: equation]

which I produced with the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \geq \frac{2^{n - r}}{2^n} = 2^{-r} \quad \forall i, \, 1 \leq i \leq \ceil*{\frac k n} \\
        \begin{aligned}
            \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_1, \ldots, \vect{x}_{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \in\ \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} &= \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \\ &\geq 2^{-\ceil*{\frac k n} r}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{gathered}\label{eq:prob}
\end{equation}
```

Now, as you can see, the `\mathbb{P}`'s are not aligned too well (and the misalignment would get even greater if line #2 was made bigger). So my question is, what would be the best way to align them?

Using `aligned` and similar environments, I'd need 1 alignment point in line #1 (the `\mathbb{P}`), two in line #2 (the first `\mathbb{P}` and the `=`), and one in line #3 (the `\geq`). I don't think it's possible to have a variable number of alignment points, so I'm lost.

Please ignore the custom commands (such as `\vect`, which is basically a wrapper for `\bm` and `\mathrm`). Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here's a full snippet that can be used to reproduce the equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \geq \frac{2^{n - r}}{2^n} = 2^{-r} \quad \forall i, \, 1 \leq i \leq \ceil*{\frac k n} \\
        \begin{aligned}
            \Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_1, \ldots, \vect{x}_{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \in\ \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} &= \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \\ &\geq 2^{-\ceil*{\frac k n} r}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{gathered}\label{eq:prob}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use nested `aligned`. Keep in mind that for some reason `aligned` adds some space before it, which you have to remove manually by, e.g. `\!`. Also you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &\mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \geq \frac{2^{n - r}}{2^n} = 2^{-r} \quad \forall i, \, 1 \leq i \leq \ceil*{\frac k n} \\
        \Longrightarrow \;&\!\begin{aligned}[t]
            \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_1, \ldots, \vect{x}_{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \in\ \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} &= \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \\ &\geq 2^{-\ceil*{\frac k n} r}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{aligned}\label{eq:prob}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

An alternative to nesting is to use a single alignment but hide the width of the first line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{\mathrm{#1}}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
        &\mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \geq \frac{2^{n - r}}{2^n} = 2^{-r} \quad \forall i, \, 1 \leq i \leq \ceil*{\frac k n} \hspace{-\textwidth}\\
            {}\Longrightarrow{} 
&\mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_1, \ldots, \vect{x}_{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \in\ \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} &&= \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^{\ceil*{\frac k n}} \mathbb{P}\left\{\vect{x}_i \in \mathscr{N}(H_{\vect{\uplambda}})\right\} \\
 &&&\geq 2^{-\ceil*{\frac k n} r}
        \end{alignedat}
   \label{eq:prob}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```